# My question about visualization got on hold

Tags: discussion, on-topic, closing-questions, reopen-closed

I think that one question I asked recently ([Showing a correlation and its p-value as a color](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/246234/105234)) got incorrectly in hold. The reason is because:

> This question appears to be off-topic because EITHER it is not about statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, or data visualization, OR it focuses on programming, debugging, or performing routine operations within a statistical computing platform. If the latter, you could try the support links we maintain

My question is how to transform some data for a heatmap visualization. Maybe it was closed because it "focuses on programming, debugging, or performing routine operations within a statistical computing platform" and I could rewrite somehow to focus more on the statistics behind. But I doubt it, because I didn't mention any program, or any error or it was closed due to being routine operation of a statistical computing platform. However, AFAIK, it is not common to "join" correlation and p-values in a single number.

How can I improve the question to be reopened?

Comment: Note that the question has since been re-opened by @Scortchi. I agree that this does not seem to have anything to do w/ programming.

Comment: Yes, but I am unsure if I should post my own answer here on meta explaining that another moderator have found it shouldn't be closed. Thanks for the edits @gung.

Comment: I don't know. I don't really have an opinion. Someone should probably do that, so this isn't officially 'unanswered'. We could let @Scortchi, if he wants, or you could answer your own question. I could write something, but I'm not sure what to put beyond my comment above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it was perhaps a mistake to close it in the first place—in any case I re-opened it after your edit & before I saw this. Sorry for any inconvenience—fortunately it was only closed a for couple of hours.

Comment: It currently has new close votes on it so it's possible it may close again.

Comment: @Glen_b, it is no longer in the close vote review queue. Someone had voted to migrate it to [SO]. I don't know why.